# How to get an IP address of iSCSI initiator which tries to connect

Tags: windows, iscsi

There is a Windows Server with iSCSI target configured, and the event log keeps filling with the message like this:

```
iSCSI initiator iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:bdbcb04e20b1 requested an invalid iSCSI target: iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:target0. The login request was rejected.
```

New message appears every second.

Previously there was an attempt to configure FreeNAS on the IP address which is now used for Windows. Nobody remembers if there were any attempts to export any targets and to connect to these targets somewhere else. The name `iqn.1994-05.com.redhat:bdbcb04e20b1` doesn't say us nothing. We found no way to get more information about this event.

The question is: how to know **the IP address** of the supposed initiator which attempts to login?

We weren't found anything about IP address in Windows logs, only name. I can go as far as capturing the traffic with Wireshark, but that's gross. I wonder why Microsoft omitted this essential information from the log?

---

Update: yet another employee appeared who remembered what that initiator could have been, so we found that system and removed (unconnected) iSCSI targets. The stream of messages stopped. This solved the original problem.

However, this doesn't solve the fundamental issue of having the IP address of the initiator in the Windows event logs. Like I said, the traffic capture is not a "solution" but an ugly workaround; it can help to identify the source *when nothing else helps* but using such a workaround on a busy server is linked to performance issues. Therefore, I don't feel this question is acceptably answered.

Comment: Probably undocumented switch that only MS support knows about. I would be surprised if it is not available.

Comment: I suspect that, but in that case I expect the "impossible" answer with the link to the respectable source, which I'd accept. For now, there are several indications that this could be impossible to do, including my own findings, but without any confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

With just Windows onboard tools and without additional software, a simple `netstat -n | find ":3260"` might do the trick. Under the assumption that the unauthorized host rapidly opens and closes socket connections, there should be a larger number of FIN_WAIT states with that source IP.

Additionally, `iqn.1994-05.com.redhat` indicates an RHEL server, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-IscsiConnection` should give you the information you need.

You can also try to filter on the target `Get-IscsiConnection -IscsiTarget iqn.2005-10.org.freenas.ctl:target0`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iscsi/get-iscsiconnection?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: While I like the idea, I am afraid it's only for established (or, "establishable") connections. In my case there is no such target on this system and it was never there. It's impossible to have a connection in principle; no connection, no help from this command.

Answer (score 1):

TCPView has your answer. Enable it and watch out incoming connections to your 3260 iSCSI port.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Answer (score 1):

To trace the IP address of the iSCSI initiator attempting to connect, you can use the Windows Event Viewer along with the iSCSI software initiator logs. Follow these steps:

Open Event Viewer:

Press Win + X and select "Event Viewer" from the menu.
Navigate to Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > iScsiPrt > Operational.
Filter the Events:

In the right pane, click on Filter Current Log....
Filter by Event Source: iScsiPrt.
Filter by Event ID: 42.
Review Event Details:

For each event, look for the Initiator Node Name or Target Name fields. The Initiator Node Name often contains the iSCSI initiator's IQN.
Additionally, check for the Connection Information field, which might contain IP information.
Unfortunately, Windows logs may not always include IP addresses directly. If the logs don't provide sufficient details, you may indeed need to resort to packet capture with Wireshark.

To capture iSCSI traffic:

Install Wireshark on the Windows Server.
Filter traffic by iscsi.
Analyze the packets for the specific initiator's IP address.

I hope this helps.

Comment: *Unfortunately, Windows logs may not always include IP addresses directly.* — this is why I am here. So is there a way to make it to **always** include it into logs? Using Wireshark for this feels like hammering nails with a microscope.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov *hammering nails with a microscope* - well, it's Windows after all...

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov you can only use the ISCSI-connector screen to find out the used IP, this is how I do it.